# How to get multiple ids from JSON and pass it to next request in jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter, beanshell

please find the attached json:

```
        "0":"10000267",
        "no":"10000267",
        "1":"2180100151-1-40",
        "article_no":"2180100151-1-40",
        "2":"550053",
        "agent_code":"550053",
        "3":"103896",
        "customer_code":"103896",
        "4":"A+",
        "grade":"A+",
        "5":"1336489",
        "id":"1336489",
        "6":"8907679958231",
        "ean_code":"8907679958231",
        "7":"315",
        "quantity":"315",
        "8":"27",
        "available_quantity":"27"
    },
    {
        "0":"10000286",
        "no":"10000286",
        "1":"2180100151-1-40",
        "article_no":"2180100151-1-40",
        "2":"550108",
        "agent_code":"550108",
        "3":"112230",
        "customer_code":"112230",
        "4":"A+",
        "grade":"A+",
        "5":"1432890",
        "id":"1432890",
        "6":"8907679958231",
        "ean_code":"8907679958231",
        "7":"494",
        "quantity":"494",
        "8":"27",
        "available_quantity":"27"
```

Now i have extracted "id" using JSON extractor and i have to pass these multiple ids in next request . How can i do this?

For Eg: I have to pass id in next request in this format id=1432890,1336489.How can i achieve this.If any one add a code that can help to achieve this it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Call the variable by their names in the next request like ${varJson_1},${varJson_2}. So, in the next request id=${varJson_1},${varJson_2}.

If you are using json extractor to fetch multiple values then below screenshot will help you to get all the values in one variable. Then, in the next request call that variable.

[image]
As shown below, foo_All contains all the values fetched by the json in one variable. Use this in the next.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok but i am getting 200 ids from JSON ,so i have to write ${varJson_1},${varJson_2} ...these 200 times ...can you please suggest me how can i deal with it

Comment: Update my comments for you requirement. Check if it helps.

Comment: I have tried with same pattern as you suggested with this i can 3-4 ids to next request. But i have to get aroud 200 ids from previous request and pass all to the next request. How can i handle this? Thanks for your valuable response.

Comment: It extracts all Ids , concatenates and stores in foo_All variable

So if you want to pass in the format id=1432890,1336489.

You can just use foo_All variable to replace all dynamic IDs

like id=${foo_All}